# Reducing file thrashing in MySQL for Windows

Tags: mysql, windows, performance, io

I am fairly new to MySQL. I have a database consisting of a few hundred table files. When I run a report I notice (through ProcMon) that MySQL is opening and closing the tables hundreds of thousands of times! That greatly affects performance. Is there some setting to direct MySQL to keep table files open until MySQL is shut down? Or at least to reduce the file thrashing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  Don't worry about it.

Plan B:  Increase `table_open_cache` to a few thousand.  (See `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'table_open_cache';`)  If that value won't stick, check the Operating System to see if it is constraining thing (`ulimit`).

Plan C:  It is rare to see an application that need over a hundred tables.  Ponder what the application is doing.  (WP, for example, uses 12 tables *per user*.  This does not scale well.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The database is not my design. I will try it out and let you know the results.